# Walker Class : extract function and wp_list_pages

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm just analyzing my custom Walker Class because it frequently skips over some post_meta data that I append to the $output HTML.

Even though the Custom Fields are set, they are ignored by the Walker. They are only shown when I go back to my functions.php, and re-run the function that sets the Custom Fields.

The **extract** function is used to obtain the arguments and skips over the arguments with the new ones provided in the walker.

invalid/numeric keys and collisions are Skipped in this case, so I would assume that my Custom Walker is being run each time.

I'll give an example of how it obtains the Custom Field:

```
$CommentCount = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'num_comments_in_Tree', true);
    if(empty($CommentCount)){
        $CommentCount = "";
    }else{$CommentCount = '&nbsp;<span style="font-size:.75em">
    comments: (' . get_post_meta($page->ID, 'num_comments_in_Tree', true)
    . ')</span>&nbsp;';}

    $MetaOutput = $CountChildren . $PageLastModifiedDate . 
    $CommentCount . $LastCommentDate . $Description;

    $output .= $indent . 
                '<li><div class="link"><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '" title="' . 
                esc_attr( wp_strip_all_tags( apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) ) ) . '">' . 
                $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>' . $MetaOutput . '</div>';
```

^See the end of the last line for the $MetaOutput.

I don't know why, if the Custom Fields are set on each page, they will only show if I re-run the function that sets the Custom Fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the function twice on itself. That way, once the walker updated the last element, it went back up to the top to update the first.